# Convert array to object - Javascript Help me

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I transform array into object?

what I want to treat:

[
"black-XXS",
"black-M",
"black-L",
"black-XL",
"black-XL",
"white-XXS",
"white-L",
"red-M",
"blue-2XL",
"blue-2XL",
"blue-2XL",
"blues"
]

result:

{
"black": {
"XXS": 1,
"M": 1,
"L": 1,
"XL": 2
},
"white": {
"XXS": 1,
"L": 1
},
"red": {
"M": 1
},
"blue": {
"2XL": 3,
"S": 1
}
}

Comment: I didn't know that, I'm sorry, I will pay attention

Comment: @esqew's comment applies to programming in general, not just here.

Answer (score 2):

Like others pointed out, this isn't a free code-writing platform. However, I will give some pointers.

First, if it's not obvious, you'll need a loop to go through the array.

Next, it looks like your string contains a couple pieces of information that you want to pull out. This means you'll need to parse the string and split them. For most of them, there is a "-", so you can try the `string.split()` method to get them separated.

Next, you need to add them to an object. Just using `object[key]` can let you dynamically access values. You need to:

1. Check if the key (the color name) exists
2. Add the key if it does not exist
3. Check if the child key (the size) exists
4. Add the key if it does not exist
5. Increment the number as appropriate

Try that out and, if you're having a specific problem, you can ask that. Otherwise, you're unlikely to get help here.

Comment: I'm trying to do this:

var result = {};

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
  color = products[i].split("-")[0]
  size = products[i].split("-")[1]

  result[color] = size
  console.log(result)  

// { black: 'XXS' }
// { black: 'M' }
// { black: 'L' }
// { black: 'XL' }
// { black: 'XL' }
// { black: 'XL', white: 'XXS' }
// { black: 'XL', white: 'L' }
// { black: 'XL', white: 'L', red: 'M' }
// { black: 'XL', white: 'L', red: 'M', blue: '2XL' }
// { black: 'XL', white: 'L', red: 'M', blue: '2XL' }
// { black: 'XL', white: 'L', red: 'M', blue: '2XL' }
}

Comment: @AlvaroMendes you're definitely not going to get help by pasting code as one line in a comment. I'm not going to try and decipher that. In the future, you should include code in the original post or, if you need to comment it, create a [CodePen](https://codepen.io)

Also, you need to explicitly say what is or isn't working.

I recommend creating a new post that has the original code in it, and lists whatever errors or problems you're running into, and trying again there. The number of downvotes on this post makes it unlikely you'll get another response, anyway.